# How to use minus operator correctly?

Tags: postgresql

For some reason the below query only returns the sum(amount) from the first query, not the intended difference between the first sum(amount) and the second sum(amount).

```
select sum(amount) from(
SELECT  
        UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
        Amount

FROM    yi_fourmpanel.card_panel
WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%some criteria%')


GROUP BY 
         UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
         Amount)

    minus

select sum(amount) from(
SELECT  
        UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
        Amount

FROM    yi_fourmpanel.card_panel
WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%some criteria%')

AND is_duplicate!=1
AND amount >0
AND currency_id = 152
AND transaction_base_type = 'debit'

GROUP BY 
         UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
         Amount)
```

Comment: Maybe the there is no intersection between the two queries.

Comment: There is no `MINUS` in Postgres. If you want the set minus use `EXCEPT`, if you want arithmetic minus use `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MINUS/EXCEPT` is set based operator not a arithmetic one. I think you want something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,  Amount
  FROM    yi_fourmpanel.card_panel
  WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%some criteria%')
    AND transaction_base_type <> 'debit'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,  -Amount
  FROM    yi_fourmpanel.card_panel
  WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%some criteria%')
    AND is_duplicate!=1
    AND amount >0
    AND currency_id = 152
    AND transaction_base_type = 'debit'
)
SELECT UNIQUE_MEM_ID, SUM(Amount) AS total
FROM cte
GROUP BY UNIQUE_MEM_ID
```